# I can't move, delete & rename any file from my HDD

Tags: permissions

I have 2 storage in my laptop. I installed Ubuntu on SSD. I can do everything in SSD, like file move, delete, and rename. but I can't do it on my HDD. I can't change permission.

Comment: What format are partition(s) on HDD? Post this in question above. `lsblk -f`

Answer (score 1):

##### Access rights, a very short "primer":

Related commands, `su`, `sudo`, `usermod`, `chmod`, `chown` and possibly more...
*check manpages of these...*

When the disk is mounted...
*(`sudo mount ...` to do that, unless it automounts as it is connected

check `ls -l /media/$USER/` to possibly find it)*

As you do `ls -l` you will se `rwx` flags for files in the first column, possibly with e.g. a `d` before them (for a dir).
Columnn three has the user owning the files(dirs) and column four the related group.

To be able to access these you either have to be logged in as that user, or belong to a group that has access - according to the second group of rwx- for a file, OR find a file that is accessible to "others" (last group of rwx).

Alternatively; be the root user
*(`sudo -i`, or `sudo ...` prepended to any commands)*

... now that is the simple access rights, ACL:s are more of this (`man acl`!), with more detail... *(I'll stop here)*.

*ONE NOTE THOUGH: I'd suggest to not use `sudo chmod/chown ...` on **OS or system** files, especially if you use the `-R` option for either of them; you might regret it quite soon.*